# Can one use the Outlook.Application.Explorer object in a standalone application?

Tags: c#, outlook

All information on the MSDN site seems to assume one is creating Outlook add-ins that use these objects.  However, I am wondering if it's possible to create new or referenced `Explorer` objects that contain `MailItems`, etc. that can be used within a **standalone application**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Office integration in a **standalone application**. This is called [Office Automation using PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4eb92bst%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Just add an assembly reference to **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll** (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll*). In code, you just need a reference to an [`Outlook.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application.aspx) instance.

```cs
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Explorer explorer = app.ActiveExplorer();
explorer.Display(); // display explorer
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Display(); // create mail message
```

You also need to be sure you [properly dispose of COM resources](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/).